# Create Dial up Connection With a batch file or comand line?

Tags: networking, batch-file, dial-up

I can dial up a dial up internet connection using rasdial command in batch file which is below

```
rasdial [Connection name] [User] [Password]
```

but I want a batch file which could actualy create a dial up connection. Shall be very grateful if someone can do it?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can re-purpose this edited script from [ghoti](http://mybroadband.co.za/vb/showthread.php/194661-Rasdial-and-advanced-batch-file-scripting):

```
@ECHO OFF

:loop
Echo Trying to connect to [Connection name] ...
rasdial [Connection name]

ping www.google.com

if NOT %ERRORLEVEL% ==0 goto failed

wait 30

goto loop 

:failed

Echo Failed to connect. [Connection name] are retarded.
```

Comment: Buddy this batch file is to connect a connection.
I want a batch file that itself creates a broadband connection...

Comment: @sam hmmm see: http://superuser.com/questions/582947/connect-to-broadband-from-command-line-windows-7 or are you trying to do something like this - http://pranavashok.com/blog/2009/07/scheduling-your-bsnl-broadband-connection-during-night-unlimited/ ?

Comment: nope it still dials existing connection i want to create a pppoe dialup connection..